# How to load QTranslator from database?

Tags: qt, qml

There is no way to load QTranslator from my own way.
I want to exclude .ts files from architecture of my app. I just want to load my languages from databse, whitch will be update from anywhere. And i don't want to load any files(.ts). Does exists the way somthing like this:
QTranslator::load(QStringList)??? QStringList is a language pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`QTranslator::translate`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtranslator.html#translate) method is virtual - which means you can simply create your own translator that extends `QTranslator` and override this (and one other) method:

```
class MyTranslator : public QTranslator
{
public:
    MyTranslator(QStringList data, QObject* parent) : 
        QTranslator(parent)
    {
        // ...
    }

    bool isEmpty() const override {
        return false; //or use your own logic to determine if data contains translations
    }

    QString translate(const char *context, const char *sourceText, const char *disambiguation = nullptr, int n = -1) const override {
        // Use the data to somehow find your translation
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't want to rewrite "translate" method, i'm just looking form the way how to "load" data into translator without .ts files.

Comment: Beacouse there is no any documentation about data structures inside QTranslator.

Comment: Whats the point in converting the translations to the qm data format? If you have your translations in some custom format from your database, just access this format inside a custom translator. Anything else will be overly complicated and error prone.

Comment: If you really have to do that for whatever reason, then good luck - there is no documentation. You will have to analyse the Qt source code and figure out that format yourself. It's a custom, internal format, nothing standardised

Comment: So sad hear'it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your goal. Why don't you get the data from your database, save it as temporary file, load via QTranslator (regular way), then delete the temporary file?

Another option is maybe the overload for:

> bool QTranslator::load(const uchar *data, int len, const QString
>   &directory = QString())

(from: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtranslator.html#load-2 ), which would allow you to load from your own structure without temp file.

Comment: Greetings, the format is the one which Qt Linguist uses, so have a look at: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/linguist-ts-file-format.html // even when it is for 4.8, it should be still valid for 5.12.